# C: structs, arrays with month and day input

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I am working on a program, that when a user enters a month number and day number, the program will print out the month and number of days (year to date). For example, if the user enters 12 30, the program will print December (DEC) 30 means 364 days YTD. The program does not need to worry about leap years. I have posted the code below. My program does not work and I am not sure why. I think my issue comes with trying to pull the month number and name from the struct month months, but I am not sure. I am using MSVS and when I try to use the debugger, I get the warnings about the errors and am told to "run for the last successful build" (there isn't one).

I get the following errors:

1. "type name is not allowed" on lines 55, 57, 58
2. 'month': illegal use of this type as an expression   on lines 55, 57, 58
3. left of '.abbrev'/'.months'/'.monumb' must have class/struct/union   on lines 55, 57, 58

   ```
    #include <stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>

   int finddata(int month, int days);

   struct month 
   {
       char name[10];
       char abbrev[4];
       int days;
       int monumb;
   };

   struct month months[12] =
   {
       { "January", "jan", 31, 1 },
       { "February", "feb", 28, 2 },
       { "March", "mar", 31, 3 },
       { "April", "apr", 30, 4 },
       { "May", "may", 31, 5 },
       { "June", "jun", 30, 6 },
       { "July", "jul", 31, 7 },
       { "August", "aug", 31, 8 },
       { "September", "sep", 30, 9 },
       { "October", "oct", 31, 10 },
       { "November", "nov", 30, 11 },
       { "December", "dec", 31, 12 }
   };

   int main()
   {
       struct month userdata;

       do
       {
           printf("Enter month and day number:");

           scanf_s("%d %d", &userdata.monumb, &userdata.days);

           finddata(userdata.monumb, userdata.days);

       } while ((userdata.monumb > 0) && (userdata.monumb < 13));


       return 0; 
   }



   int finddata(int months, int days)
   {
       int i;
       int total = 0;

       for (i = 1; i != month.monumb[i]; i++) //**(line 55)**
       {
           puts(month.name[i]); //**(line 57)**
           puts(month.abbrev[i]); //**(line 58)**
       }
       printf("%d means", months);

       if (months == 1)
       {
           total = days;
       }
       else if (months == 2)
       {
           total = days + 31;
       }
       else if (months == 3)
       {
           total = 31 + 28 + days;
       }
       else if (months == 4)
       {
           total = 31 + 28 + 31 + days;
       }
       else if (months == 5)
       {
           total = 31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + days;
       }
       else if (months == 6)
       {
           total = 31 + 28 + 31 + 30 + 31 + days;
       }
       else if (months == 7)
       {
           total = (31 * 3) + 28 + (30 * 2) + days;
       }
       else if (months == 8)
       {
           total = (31 * 4) + 28 + (30 * 2) + days;
       }
       else if (months == 9)
       {
           total = (31 * 5) + 28 + (30 * 2) + days;
       }
       else if (months == 10)
       {
           total = (31 * 5) + 28 + (30 * 3) + days;
       }
       else if (months == 11)
       {
           total = (31 * 6) + 28 + (30 * 3) + days;
       }
       else if (months == 12)
       {
           total = (31 * 6) + 28 + (30 * 4) + days;
       }
       else
       {
           //blank
       }

       printf("%d days YTD.", total);

       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: "does not work" is not a good problem description. Please state the input, expected output and actual output. And have you used a debugger or even basic debug print statements to trace the execution of your program? Where do things start going wrong?

Comment: I would advise you use a `switch` statement for `months` in your `finddata` function.

Comment: `for (i = 1; i != month.monumb[i]; i++)` What are you trying to do there? We've already pointed out the problems with this in the deleted question you posted earlier today. Where is the variable `month` defined? Why are you using an array access for `monumb` which is not an array? Does your code even compile?

Comment: `for (i = 1; i != month.monumb[i]; i++)
    {
        puts(month.name[i]);
        puts(month.abbrev[i]);
    }
    printf("%d means", months);` --> `printf("%s (%s) %d means ", month.name[months-1], month.abbrev[months-1], days);`

Comment: As an aside, you also have some redundant information in your struct. You store the month number, but the index in the array will also correspond to month number.

Comment: @kaylum should probably be 'for (i = 1; months != month.monumb[i]; i++)'. I am trying to compare the month number the user entered with the months numbers in the array struct month months[12]. But it's clear I am not doing that correctly. My code does not compile.

Comment: For the third time, `month` is not a defined variable. You  cannot access a variable that doesn't exist. And the local `months` variable is hiding the global `months` variable so that doesn't work well either. Assuming you rename the global variable to `global_months` then that line would be: for `(i = 0; i != global_months[i].monumb; i++)`

Comment: The errors are listed right before the code.

Comment: Are you using a C++ compiler to compile your C code by any chance?

Comment: I think line 55 (`for (i = 1; i != month.monumb[i]; i++)` should be `for (i = 1; i != months[i].monumb; i++)` — your array of month information is called `months`, and you access an element of the array with `months[i]`, and so on.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you for your help. I am using microsoft visual studio. I made the change you suggested and helped my program at least compile; however, it is still not functioning correctly.

Comment: I didn't look at the algorithm — getting the code to compile was the first step.  You've not explained, yet, how it is not functioning correctly.  What input do you give? What output do you get?  What output should you get? Why?  Apart from the 'why', this is part of the basic material for an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: Array indices start at 0; you won't ever find dates in January.

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in this loop:

```
    for (i = 1; i != month.monumb[i]; i++) //**(line 55)**
    {
        puts(month.name[i]); //**(line 57)**
        puts(month.abbrev[i]); //**(line 58)**
    }
```

1. You named the global `struct month` array `months`, but refer to it as `month`. To match the names, change the definition to `struct month month[12] =`.
2. You try to index the structure elements instead of the structure array. Put the index brackets after the structure array name, i. e. `month[…].…`.
3. The loop condition intended to search for the `months`th array element is wrong, and at all we don't need a loop, since the array is sorted.

To correct points 2 and 3, replace the whole loop with:

```
    puts(month[months-1].name);
    puts(month[months-1].abbrev);
```

Answer (score -2):

Your for loop in finddata treats month.monumb as an array, when it is an integer. Please use better names, too. I suspect you're not clear on how an array of structs works.

So you don't need a for loop to find the month name. You can just index the array;

```
    puts(months.name[userdata.monumb]); //**(line 57)**
    puts(months.abbrev[userdata.monumb]); //**(line 58)**
```

Comment: I'm trying to take the number for months that the user entered and compare it to the month months[12] struct array. When there is a match it should print the name of the month and the abbreviation. That's what I am trying to do and I'm having a hard time with it.